# Markdown cannot create link inside inline code snippet

Tags: markdown

Let's say I have the following inline code-snippet:

```
Signature: `createLayer(styles: Styles, preferredStyle: string)`
```

Signature: `createLayer(styles: Styles, preferredStyle: string)`

How to I add a link to the code snippet?

I tried the following, but the snippet is no longer inline.

```
Signature: <pre>createLayer(styles: [Styles](MY_LINK_HERE), preferredStyle: string)</pre>
```

Signature:

```
createLayer(styles: Styles, preferredStyle: string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inline code spans](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code) use `<code>` tags, not `<pre>` tags. So try:

```
Signature: <code>createLayer(styles: [Styles](http://example.com), preferredStyle: string)</code>
```

Which renders as:

> Signature: `createLayer(styles: Styles, preferredStyle: string)`